# Create a list item dynamically using two file paths JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Ok I will explain this the best I can

what I would like to do

is create a Jquery function that will create a list from two different folders so it would give me something like this for up to 30 images

```
<div id="box">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="images/test1.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/test2.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/test3.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it this possible whats the simplest way of writing this?

thanks

sho

Answer (score 0):

```
function addItems(num) {
  var myList = $('#box > ul').first();
  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    myList.append('<li><a href="images/test' + i + '.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test' + i + '.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>');
  }
}
```

Calling this function will find the first `ul` item within the `div` with id 'box' and append a bunch of `li` elements to it. The number of elements you want to add is passed as the parameter, and so if you pass '5' you will get:

```
<li><a href="images/test1.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/test2.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test2.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/test3.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test3.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/test4.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test4.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
<li><a href="images/test5.jpg"><img src="imagesthumbs/test5.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
```

...added to your `ul`.

You can call it with something like the following, assuming that there is a `div` with id 'box' containing a `ul` in your html page:

```
<script>
$(function() { // wrapping it this way ensures the page is loaded and the elements exist
  addItems(5);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you use first() method? You unnecessarily created additional jQuery object.

Comment: @avall - in case of multiple `ul` children.

Comment: could you explain why this works so in the future I can apply it else where

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two arrays as two different folders. You can try this

```
var images = ["test1.jpg", "test2.jpg"];
var imagesthumbs = ["test1.jpg", "test2.jpg"];

var ul = $("<ul/>");
$.each(images, function(i, val){
   $("<li/>")
   .append($("a", {href:"images/"+val}).append("img", {src:imagesthumbs[i], alt:""}))
   .appendTp(ul);
});

$("#box").append(ul);
```